# How to concert a txt file into list without comma in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list

I have a sitename.txt it looks like this:

```
  airipokeramen                  
  888beijing                    
  88buffet                      
  adbuffalo                     
  aerospacea3                   
  airipokeramen                 
  aiya                          
  aki                           
  akisushi                      
  arcticbites                   
  asackofpotatoes               
  asiabuffetchattanooga         
  asiacuisines                  
  asiancook                     
  atlantacafe
```

How can I convert it into list like this:

```
['airipokeramen','888beijing',...,'atlantacafe']
```

I tried use pandas,sometimes it not works:

```
import pandas
data=pandas.read_csv('sitename.txt')
site_names = data["iripokeramen"].values.tolist()
site_names
```

error:

```
KeyError: 'iripokeramen'
```

Comment: What's an `iripokeramen`?

Comment: @MrNobody33 thanks for finding that dupe!

Comment: The way you used indicates a column called "iripokeramen" in a csv file which is not the case.

Comment: You're welcome man! @AdamSmith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open('filename') as file:
    your_list = [line.strip() for line in file.readlines()]
```

Pandas isn't necessary if it's a simple text file.